# Считать матрицу из файла и в последней строке найти первый отрицательный элемент. Зафиксировать его номер. Подскажите как его найти и зафиксировать

Tags: c++

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    int i, j, a[3][4];// Входные данные 

    FILE* matrixfile;// Создание файла 

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)// Вносим данные в матрицу 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 20 - 10;// Генератор случайного числа в диапазоне от -10 до 10
        }
    }
    matrixfile = fopen("matrixfile.txt", "w");// Открытие файла 

    if ((matrixfile = fopen("matrixfile.txt", "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Ошибка открытия файла\n");
        exit(1);// Завершение работы программы 
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)// Записываем матрицу в файл
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            fprintf(matrixfile, "%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(matrixfile, "\n\n");
        
    }
    fclose(matrixfile);

    matrixfile = fopen("matrixfile.txt", "r");// Чтение файла
```

Comment: вы писали с `fprintf` . ситывайте с `fscanf`

Comment: `fscanf(matrixfile, "%d ", &(a[i][j]));`